# What are the basic immigration requirements for Iceland for a non EU citizen?

Tags: immigration, iceland

What are the complete and specific requirements for an Asian citizen who intends to immigrate to Iceland. I am seeking for professional and authentic guidance.

Comment: Have you visited Iceland's Multicultural and Information Centre site which has full details? http://www.mcc.is/english/extra/immigrate-to-iceland/non-eea

Comment: @Dorothy Yeah. I did visit that site before posting a question here.The information there is quite comprehensive and too detailed. What i want is a summary or brief information. Thank you

Comment: Well, you *asked* for "**complete and specific requirements**". Nevertheless, here's a summary: If you don't have family in Iceland, then you need a job in Iceland or intend to study full-time at an Icelandic university.

Answer (score 1):

[Fjölmenningarsetur, the Multicultural and Information Centre](http://www.mcc.is/english/first-steps-in-iceland-none-eea/kaflar/nr/1713), offers an overview and checklist that citizens of non EEA/EFTA countries need when intended to immigrate to Iceland.

> Citizens of states that are not member states of the EEA or EFTA agreements must apply for a residence permit at the Directorate of Immigration if they intend to stay in Iceland for longer than three months.
>
> Basic conditions for a residence permit:
>
> **Secure support**
>
> The applicant must be able to show secure support and that means any of the following:
>
> - Employment wages or fixed regular payments.
> - Private funds (for example in a bank account).
> - Payments from other close members of family (if the applicant is a child under 18 or a parent 67 or older).
>
> If support is in the form of employment wages or fixed regular payments you must present an employment contract, payslips or a certificate from the employer on job percentage and duration of employment.
>
> If it is a question of private funds, which the applicant uses for support, they must be in a currency listed at the Central Bank of Iceland (www.sedlabanki.is). The same applies to student loans or education grants for students.
>
> Information on reference for minimum support can be found on the [Directorate of Immigration's website](http://www.utl.is/index.php/en/basic-requirements1#support).
>
> **Secure housing**
>
> By secure housing it means that the applicant can establish that he can stay in a house, that is registered as a resident housing in the real estate registry, with the consent of the registered owner. The registered owner of a house must sign a form which confirms this
>
> **Health insurance**
>
> The applicant must buy a health insurance called medical expense insurance from an insurance company with an operating license in Iceland. The insurance must be valid for at least six months from the registration of a legal residence or until the person has gained the right to be medically insured in Iceland.